# Where can I ask questions related to Yoga and Exercise?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask questions related to Yoga and Morning exercises. Which website would be better for it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[**Physical Fitness**](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/) is for you. You can ask questions related to [Yoga](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yoga) and [Exercise](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercise).