# On which site should I ask about calculation of energy spent running uphill, and adapting my daily run accordingly?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where on Stack Exchange does the following question fit best?

> What is the flat ground distance equivalent of 500 metres running uphill with an incline of 10%?
>
> To explain the question: I ran 500 meters uphill. This costs energy, which can be measured in joules etc.
>
> So, I guess my question is, if I wanna replace my daily run of 4 kilometres, how many times should I run up that hill?

Comment: i've looked but there doesn't seem to  be a good site, for this, but then again, i don't know this site that well, so can you help me find a good site for this?

Comment: This _might_ be appropriate for [fitness.se].

Comment: edited question looks like a duplicate of [Where can I ask questions related to Yoga and Exercise?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170848/165773)

Comment: yoga and exercise are very generic, my question also has a physics component to it.

Comment: You probably shouldn't worry about the physics aspect of it _per se_ - treat it as straight exercise, and ask it that way on [fitness.se]. There are almost certainly other aspects than straight energy use that need to be accounted for.

Comment: I edited your question to make it a proper site-recommendation question, and include the bit about sports in the title to differentiate it from a simple Pythagorean equation; feel free to edit in more info, or correct anything I might have changed the meaning of. If you are to ask on [fitness.se], I'm not sure how they operate but you may want to include what kind of exercise you're looking for - you can spend the same amount of energy running uphill for a short time or longer on flat land, but that doesn't train your body the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is in the same spirit as [Actual amount of calories, I'm burning when riding bike](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/18640/24237) on [Physical Fitness Stack Exchange](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/).

If you compare it with their Help Center article [What topics can I ask about here?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I can certainly see your question being part of

> - choosing a training program

so my guess would be it's on topic there. You'll soon find out, as I saw you posted it already: [What is the flat ground distance equivalent of 500 metres running uphill with an incline of 10%?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/40842/24237)